# Can't affect values to a simple Double[] table which is always null - Comparaison between 2 codes

Tags: java, gps, nmea

I've asked a similar question about it : [Can't affect values to a simple Double[] table which is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608871/java-cant-affect-values-to-a-simple-double-table-which-is-always-null/20608945#20608945)

I have a TXT file containing NMEA frames. I retrieve the latitude and the longitude of $GPGGA and $GPRMC frames. Then I convert the latitude and longitude into Decimal Degrees. The first version of my code is working great. Then I made a second one, more structured, but which doesn't work.

**Here is the second version of my code which doesn't work :**

```
/**
 * Updating position on Google Maps
 * @param values
 */
public void showMyPosition(String values)
{
    String[]selectedposition=values.split(",");
    Double[]decimalcoordinates=new Double[2];
    if(selectedposition.length>1 || selectedposition[0].equals("$GPGGA"))
    {
        int[]coordinatesposition=new int[]{2,4};
        decimalcoordinates = convertNmeaToDecimal(selectedposition, coordinatesposition);
    }
    else if(selectedposition.length>1 || selectedposition[0].equals("$GPRMC"))
    {
        int[]coordinatesposition=new int[]{3,5};
        decimalcoordinates = convertNmeaToDecimal(selectedposition, coordinatesposition);
    }

    LatLng position=new LatLng(decimalcoordinates[0],decimalcoordinates[1]);
    googlemap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("You are here !").position(position));
    googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 19));
}   

/**
 * Convert NMEA coordinates into Decimal degrees coordinates.
 * @param nmeaframes 
 *      Contains all the NMEA frame
 * @param coordinatesposition
 *      Contains the position of the latitude and longitude into nmeaframes[]
 * @return decimalcoordinates*      
 */
public Double[] convertNmeaToDecimal(String[]nmeaframes, int[]coordinatesposition)
{
    Double nmeacoordinates=null;
    Double[]decimalcoordinates=new Double[2];

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        nmeacoordinates=Double.parseDouble(nmeaframes[coordinatesposition[i]]);
        decimalcoordinates[i]=Math.floor(nmeacoordinates/100)+(nmeacoordinates-Math.floor(nmeacoordinates/100)*100)/60;
    }
    return decimalcoordinates;
}
```

**Here is my LogCat :**

```
12-17 14:47:03.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 14:47:03.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6769): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "A"
12-17 14:47:03.476: E/AndroidRuntime(6769):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
```

I think I'm so in my code, that I can no longer see my mistakes. It seems to be the same as my precedent question. But I can't solve it.

Can you help me please ?

**EDIT - This is a really careless mistakes... Thanks to Alex Walker who help me to pointed my error**

> To give the original functionality, you need to change both of those `||` operators to `&&`. That way it will check both cases as required. That is, use:

```
if(selectedposition.length>1 && selectedposition[0].equals("$GPGGA"))
```

and

```
else if(selectedposition.length>1 && selectedposition[0].equals("$GPRMC"))
```

Comment: Would this be better on codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @TimB No, it wouldn't. Code Review is for reviewing code (improving code style and stuff), not understanding where errors come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These code samples are extremely long and very similar, so it's painfully difficult to pin down what the actual problem is.

However one obvious mistake that does stand out is in these lines from version 2:

```
if(selectedposition.length>1 || selectedposition[0].equals("$GPGGA"))
```

and

```
else if(selectedposition.length>1 || selectedposition[0].equals("$GPRMC"))
```

According to your version 1 code, the algorithm should check that `selectedposition.length>1`, and if it is, then go and try to do stuff. If it isn't, don't do anything.

But in the version 2 code listed above, the block

```
else if(selectedposition.length>1 || selectedposition[0].equals("$GPRMC"))
```

will NEVER be called unless the input is exactly one character long.

To give the original functionality, you need to change both of those `||` operators to `&&`. That way it will check both cases as required. That is, use:

```
if(selectedposition.length>1 && selectedposition[0].equals("$GPGGA"))
```

and

```
else if(selectedposition.length>1 && selectedposition[0].equals("$GPRMC"))
```

Comment: Omg... I feel really stupid now... This little inattention is the cause of my application crash. Really really thank you a lot @AlexWalker.

Comment: No problem at all, very easy to make tiny errors in long functions!